# Sed match exact

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm currently using `'s/string/new_string/g'` to go through some CSV files, however I'm running into difficulty in the following scenario:

I want to replace instances of `'192.168.0.11'`, however it's also catching instances of `'192.168.0.111'`.

How can I ensure sed only grabs `'192.168.0.11'` and not `'192.168.0.111'`? I'll obviously have to repeat this for many variables, so something easily scalable would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: could you show your current sed command is and example data please

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure what the regex you are using is, but if you want an exact match of '192.168.0.11' you can use: 
`s/\<192\.168\.0\.11\>//g`

The `\<\>` force an exact match.

Comment: Note that `.` matches any character, so `192.168.0.11` will match `192.168.05.1`. You should also quote the dots with backslash (`$ sed 's/\<192\.168\.0\.11\>//g'`).

Comment: follow up answer that may be worth checking  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108120/replace-an-exact-match-for-a-double-underscore-with-a-string-using-sed/70108412#70108412