# awk to replace a line in a text file and save it

Tags: awk, sed

I want to open a text file that has a list of 500 IP addresses. I want to make the following changes to one of the lines and save the file. Is it possible to do that with `awk` or `sed`?

current line :

```
100.72.78.46:1900
```

changes :

```
100.72.78.46:1800
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace whole line with sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822097/how-to-replace-whole-line-with-sed)

Comment: The answer to any "Is it possible to do that with awk" question about manipulating text is "yes". Please read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following:

```
sed -ie 's/100.72.78.46:1900/100.72.78.46:1800/' file.txt
```

The `i` option will update the original file, and a backup file will be created. This will edit only the first occurrence of the pattern. If you want to replace all matching patterns, add a `g` after the last `/`

This solution, however (as point out on the comments) fails in many other instances, such as `72100372578146:190032`, which would transform into  `72100.72.78.46:180032`.

To circumvent that, you'd have to do an exact match, and also **not** treat the `.` as special character (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196185/sed-match-exact)):

```
sed  -ie 's/\<100\.72\.78\.46:1900\>/100.72.78.46:1800/g' file.txt
```

note the `\.` and the `\<...\>` "word boundary" notation for the exact match. This solution worked for me on a Linux machine, but not on a MAC. For that, you would have to use a slightly different syntax (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190334/sed-on-mac-os-x)):

```
sed  -ie 's/[[:<:]]100\.72\.78\.46:1900[[:>:]]/100.72.78.46:1800/g' file.txt
```

where the `[[:<:]]...[[:>:]]` would give you the exact match.

finally, I also realized that, if you have only one IP address per line, you could also use the special characters `^$` for the beginning and end of line, preventing the erroneous replacement:

```
sed  -ie 's/^100\.72\.78\.46:1900$/100.72.78.46:1800/g' file.txt
```

Comment: That will fail given various input file contents. For example it will convert `72100372578146:190032` to `72100.72.78.46:180032`. It's always easy to find/change the text you want but much harder to not find/change text you don't want and a script that produces the output you expect given some small sample input is the starting point to finding a solution, not the end point. It's important when posting sample input/output to put some effort into considering the cases you think might be hard to handle and do not want found/changed, not just 1 sunny day case.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I'll edit my response to make it work in a more general sense. Thanks!