# replace an exact match for a double underscore with a string using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace an exact match for a double underscore with a string.

```
sed -i 's/\<__\>/.abc.def__/g' file
```

But this leaves the file unchanged.  Grateful for any pointers.
follow up from [Sed match exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196185/sed-match-exact)

Comment: `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries and `_` is a word character. Remove them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but then I insert the string in cases where I have a triple underscore too.  How would I match only __?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample string? The main problem doing it with sed is that the match lands in the result (`__` is not removed). I'd use `perl` here, `perl -i -pe 's/(?<!_)__(?!_)/.abc.def__/g' file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew AFM_7499_190512_110136_001_p_EQ4H_1_s60_0012__386___Day_

Comment: I still think Perl is better, but `sed -E  's/([^_]|^)__([^_]|$)/\1.abc.def__\2/g' file` can work, too, if you do not have overlapping matches. See https://ideone.com/9SBMW9

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can I trouble you to explain this as the answer?  If you don't have time no problem and thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no overlapping matches (and your provided input has none), a `sed` like this will do:

```sh
sed -E  's/([^_]|^)__([^_]|$)/\1.abc.def__\2/g' file > newfile
```

Here, `([^_]|^)__([^_]|$)` matches and captures into Group 1 (`\1`) any char other than `_` or start of string (`([^_]|^)`), then matches `__`, and then captures into Group 2 (`\2`) any char other than `_` or end of string (`([^_]|$)`).

If there can be overlapping matches, `sed` becomes rather difficult to use here. A perfect alternative would be using

```sh
perl -pe 's/(?<!_)__(?!_)/.abc.def__/g' file > newfile
perl -i -pe 's/(?<!_)__(?!_)/.abc.def__/g' file
```

The `(?<!_)__(?!_)` regex contains two lookarounds, `(?<!_)` negative lookbehind that makes sure there is no `_` char immediately to the left of the current location, and `(?!_)` negative lookahead makes sure there is no `_` char immediately to the right of the current location.

See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/9SBMW9):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='AFM_7499_190512_110136_001_p_EQ4H_1_s60_0012__386___Day_'

sed -E  's/([^_]|^)__([^_]|$)/\1.abc.def__\2/g' <<< "$s"
# => AFM_7499_190512_110136_001_p_EQ4H_1_s60_0012.abc.def__386___Day_
perl -i -pe 's/(?<!_)__(?!_)/.abc.def__/g' <<< "$s"
# => AFM_7499_190512_110136_001_p_EQ4H_1_s60_0012.abc.def__386___Day_
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^/\n/;:a;ta;s/\n__($|[^_])/.abc.def__\1\n/;ta;s/\n(_+|[^_]+)/\1\n/;ta;s/\n//' file
```

Prepend a newline to the current line.

Pattern match through the line using the newline as a delimiter.

If the pattern is matched, replace with the required string and step the delimiter over the replacement.

Otherwise, shift the delimiter along the line  and repeat.

At the end of line, remove the introduced newline.

---

Alternative:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^_])__($|[^_])/\1\n\2/g;s//\1\n\2/g;s/\n/.abc.def__/g' file
```